# Dual-Booting vanilla Ubuntu and Ubuntu Studio on an EFI machine

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I was able to successfully install (vanilla) Ubuntu on an EFI machine recently, but I am running into issues installing Ubuntu Studio as a dual-boot.

If I used the guided partitioning mode, Ubuntu Studio threw an error that it can not install Grub for whatever reason. After doing a manual installation, Grub successfully installs, but GRUB does not appear and my system boots directly into vanilla Ubuntu.

While I don't mind returning to legacy boot or nuking the entire system to get this to work, it would be preferable to find a way to get this working under UEFI, just for the learning experience and to keep my (current) system working.

So, how can I get my dual-boot working in a sane way?